# Make a div fill the whole page in height

Tags: javascript, html, css, height

I have a page with this structure:

topbar (100% width)
sidebar content

i want the sidebar to fill all the remaining space of the screen in height.

I've tried with height: 100% in my css but doesn't work.

How can i do this? There is a way to do it using css or i have to use Javascript?

Comment: Please can you post the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve this you need make sure the sidebar's parent containers have heights of 100%, too.

So, if you have a sidebar div, you have the `body` container, and the `html` container.

```
html, body, #sidebar { height: 100%; }
```

Comment: perfect, it works but there is a problem: the topbar is fixed so the body as a 40px padding: adding 100% to the height of body, html, contenitor make the page have the scrollbar, there is a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the height of body height to 100% too? If not it won't fill up the rest of the page.